# Airflow: Issue connecting to docker image from dockerOperator: docker in docker case

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

Issue connecting to docker image from dockerOperator:

I have DockerOperator implemented in my DAG.

- When running on Linux installed environment whole DAG is working fine.
- When running via docker-compose on windows I got following issue:

```
Error while fetching server API version: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=2375):
Max retries exceeded with url: /version (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f470ec46b10>:
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

- I assume this issue resembles following: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/
- It might be related to Docker networking topic. I attached picture of my solution.

DockerOperator needs docker_url to be pointed out. Neither of following approaches worked for me:

- docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock"
- docker_url="tcp://localhost:2375"

I use Airflow docker image build based on Airflow 1.10.12.

Any Ideas how to solve this problem?[image]

Comment: **Above case was related to running docker image in a docker image.**

As a solution we used latest docker-compose from:
http://apache-airflow-docs.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/docs/apache-airflow/latest/start/docker.html

inner docker image has to have access to docker socket which can be accomplished via volume plus access rights
-v  /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock